# Включить в DOM, исключить из DOMа

Tags: php, javascript, битрикс

Мне дали такое задание "Само поп-ап окно до вызова не должно находится в DOM-дереве, а лишь подгружаться при вызове окна и удалятся при его закрытии." Это компонента "веб-форма"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее вего вы не правильно поняли задание, сгенерированный popup не находится в DOM , он должен находится в js переменной. При обращениее через js событие вы просто помещаете данный код в div , да div находится DOM, но в задаче говорится именно про popup.

В любом случае кудабы вы не вставляли, вам нужно в js указать куда вставлять, а куда вставлять в любом случае находится в DOM . (будь то div , document, window, значение тега, атрибут тега и т.д...)

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно сгенерировать pop-up на javascript, а затем при обращении к нему вставить в dom.

Т.о. до вызова pop-up нет в dom.

Comment: Я понимаю, но код надо вставить в  пустой див, а пустой див  будет изначально в доме, что такого не должно быть...

Comment: @NNN `createElement` и `appendChild`, нет?

Comment: @NNN Пустой div может быть в доме, может и не быть. Body ведь в любом случае будет?) `$('body').append('<div id="popup">Window</div>');`